# Combine 2D Plot with 3D Plot

Tags: plotting

I want to combine 2D Plot with 3D Plot, where the 2D Plot should be placed on one of the "walls" of the 3D Plot. I have used an idea from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115811/6015) and ended with something like that (where the functions are only some example without a meaning)

```
p1 = Plot3D[Sin[d+s] - Cos[s], {s, 0, Pi}, {d, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "d", "Sin[d+s]-Cos[s]"}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]];
p2 = Plot[{(t/Pi)^2, Sqrt[t/Pi]}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}];
p3 = Graphics3D @@ (FullGraphics[p2] /. 
     Line[pts__] :> Line[pts /. {s_, d_} :> {s, 0, d}]);
Show[p1, p3]
```

I think the plot I obtain is fine, however, I got also some Axes and Ticks errors and the whole background is red, even if I turn the errors off.

What do I wrong?

Comment: The problem comes from FullGraphics[p2]. p2 is a list of length 2. The first elements contains all the graphics primitives, the second the options. FullGraphics has problems with the options. Therefore, write FullGraphics[p2[[1]]]

Comment: Great, it works! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can also directly draw the two 3D curves by use `ParametricPlot3D`,

```
{x, y, z} /. {x -> t, y -> 0, z -> (t/Pi)^2}
{x, y, z} /. {x -> t, y -> 0, z -> Sqrt[t/Pi]}
```

```
p1 = Plot3D[Sin[d + s] - Cos[s], {s, 0, Pi}, {d, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "d", "Sin[d+s]-Cos[s]"}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]];
p4 = 
   ParametricPlot3D[{{x, y, z} /. {x -> t, y -> 0, z -> (t/Pi)^2}, {x,
        y, z} /. {x -> t, y -> 0, z -> Sqrt[t/Pi]}}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}];
Show[p1, p4]
```